# How to fix "self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)" error

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to run a YOLO model described here [link](https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo2) and there is a part where I have to run

```
train_imgs, seen_train_labels = parse_annotation(train_annot_folder, train_image_folder, labels=LABELS)

train_batch = BatchGenerator(train_imgs, generator_config, norm=normalize)

valid_imgs, seen_valid_labels = parse_annotation(valid_annot_folder, valid_image_folder, labels=LABELS)

valid_batch = BatchGenerator(valid_imgs, generator_config, norm=normalize, jitter=False)
```

The `parse_annotation` function is defined as:

```
def parse_annotation(ann_dir, img_dir, labels=[]):
    all_imgs = []
    seen_labels = {}

    for ann in sorted(os.listdir(ann_dir)):
        img = {'object':[]}

        tree = ET.parse(ann_dir + ann)

        for elem in tree.iter():
            if 'filename' in elem.tag:
                img['filename'] = img_dir + elem.text
            if 'width' in elem.tag:
                img['width'] = int(elem.text)
            if 'height' in elem.tag:
                img['height'] = int(elem.text)
            if 'object' in elem.tag or 'part' in elem.tag:
                obj = {}

                for attr in list(elem):
                    if 'name' in attr.tag:
                        obj['name'] = attr.text

                        if obj['name'] in seen_labels:
                            seen_labels[obj['name']] += 1
                        else:
                            seen_labels[obj['name']] = 1

                        if len(labels) > 0 and obj['name'] not in labels:
                            break
                        else:
                            img['object'] += [obj]

                    if 'bndbox' in attr.tag:
                        for dim in list(attr):
                            if 'xmin' in dim.tag:
                                obj['xmin'] = int(round(float(dim.text)))
                            if 'ymin' in dim.tag:
                                obj['ymin'] = int(round(float(dim.text)))
                            if 'xmax' in dim.tag:
                                obj['xmax'] = int(round(float(dim.text)))
                            if 'ymax' in dim.tag:
                                obj['ymax'] = int(round(float(dim.text)))

        if len(img['object']) > 0:
            all_imgs += [img]

    return all_imgs, seen_labels
```

Whenever I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\a\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-160-54bc9b7f63fe>", line 1, in <module>
    train_imgs, seen_train_labels = parse_annotation(train_annot_folder, train_image_folder, labels=LABELS)

  File "<ipython-input-159-0d23145e88db>", line 8, in parse_annotation
    tree = ET.parse(ann_dir + ann)

  File "C:\Users\a\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)

  File "C:\Users\a\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

I am not familiar with xml and ElementTree so I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `argparse` or command line parsing?

Comment: `ann_dir + ann` is not a well-formed XML document. It is hard to say more than that without a [mcve].